# Why is REPLICATION ROLE showing replication role?

Tags: memgraphdb

When I use Memgraph 2.2.0 (Docker using memgraph-platform image) and I run the `SHOW REPLICATION ROLE` in the result column says `replication mode` and is showing replication role. This seems off to me, or are ROLE and MODE aliases?

Comment: It got fixed in https://github.com/memgraph/memgraph/commit/21ad5d43280baf5c6393fd6c2c15a80e5ecb91b9, so you should probably just update your Memgraph version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @PhobosFerro has noticed, this was a bug that was Fixed with release of [Memgraph 2.3.1](https://memgraph.com/docs/memgraph/changelog#v231---jun-23-2022). You need to update your Memgraph Platform.